# Resize images to preset aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to resize a grid of images on a webpage according to screen size, whether 3 or 4 columns automatically determined. The image width stays identical for all columns, but the height is variable.

I need ALL the images to resize at a perfect 1:1.5 ratio, regardless of actual image size/ratio, without stretching, just cutting off the overflow. My first thought was to change the "h" math to `w * 1.5`, but no luck.

```
(function() {
    var $K = $('#posts').css("position", "relative");
    var rsz_i = undefined;
    var rs z = function() {
        if (rsz_i != undefined)
            clearTimeout(rsz_i);
        rsz_i = setTimeout(real_rsz, 100);
    };
    var first = true;
    var real_rsz = function() {
        var C = Math.ceil($("#posts-container").width() / 350);
        var w = Math.ceil($("#posts-container").width() / C);
        console.log("rsz", C, w);
        $(".entry").css({ "width": w+"px" });
        setTimeout(function() {
            var col = 0, y = [], h = 0;
            $(".entry").each(function() {
                if (!y[col])
                    y[col] = 0;
                $(this).css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "left": (col * w)+"px",
                    "top": y[col]+"px"
                });
                y[col] += $(this).height();
                h = Math.max(h, y[col]);
                col += 1;
                if (col >= C)
                    col = 0;
            });
            $("#posts").css("height", h+"px");
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                setTimeout(real_rsz, 150);
            }
        }, 150);
    };
    $K.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $(window).on("resize", rsz);
        rsz();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need the overflow, just put the images inside a div with dimensions in 1:1.5 ratio and set the overflow property of the div to hidden. Also, set the image width to take up 100% of the parent div. This will prevent the image from stretching.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
#clipped {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/velka/watch-vector.jpg">
</div>
<br>
<div id="clipped">
  <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/velka/watch-vector.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. But the image is aligned from the top edge and cuts off the y overflow on the bottom. How can I have the image centered both x and y in the div? margin: auto auto isn't working, nor is vert/horz align.

Comment: I updated the snippet. I hope that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.story-small img').each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if(width > maxWidth){
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if(height > maxHeight){
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding another math var with a separate "r" to represent ratio height at the end of the code.

```
        var w = Math.ceil($("#posts-container").width() / C);
    console.log("rsz", r);
    $(".entry").css({ "height": (r*1.5)+"px" });
};
$K.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", rsz);
    rsz();
});
```

});